# How can I make a circular object appear perfectly round?

Tags: objects

How do you make a spherical/ovular object in Blender?

I can make square objects, and I can make a UV sphere. But how would I make an object that appears spherical in render?

Comment: Down-voted because you don't explain well (as you can see both answers your got are quite different), You need to explain why adding a circle/sphere does not satisfy your needs.

Comment: @ideasman42 sorry about that. About the answers though, they both answered my question well. They're both good answers I'd say, as Haunt_House said below, they're both important.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Are you looking for "Smooth Shading"?

[image: Smooth/Flat Shading]

Comment: This isn't really as smooth as adding more vertices.

Answer (score 11):

In the main menu:
Add > Mesh > UVSphere
Add > Mesh > IcoSphere

In the tool properties panel you can adjust
the resolution. Later you can even add a
*[subdivision surface](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf)* modifier
to it. Note that this way a sphere is
represented with polygons.

Theoretically a ray-tracer can render real spheres,
but cycles does not support it. Even meta-balls are
rendered polygonally, not as real smooth surfaces.

Comment: Sorry I meant sphere. Oops, :(

Comment: I wish I could say you both were right, but I think the answer below is better. I'd one up you both if I could though.

Comment: Both answers are important. Smooth shading only affects the surface of the object, but not it's outline. If you use smooth shading on a 32 vert circle, the outline will look edgy. Btw, you can give upvotes to both answers.

Comment: @Haunt_House not enough rep

Comment: I'm not seeing the "tool properties panel".  Is there a keyboard shortcut to view that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`subdivide`](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/subdivide.html?highlight=subdivide) with a smoothness of 1:

Mesh before subdividing:
[image]

Subdivided with no smoothing:
[image: Subdivided with no smoothing]

Subdivided with smoothing of 1:
[image: Subdivided with smoothing of 1]

Comment: This way the polygon doesn't approach a sphere — more like a smooth but bumpy rock.

Answer (score 1):

To make a UV sphere rounder, increase the number of segments and rings in the "Add UV Sphere" panel. These are good values to use:

[image: Add UV Sphere panel]