# Model in Blender differ from model in stl file

Tags: export

So recently, I imported a file that has my desired model in it from MMD to Blender. However, when I exported the model in a stl file, the model looks very unusual.

[image]
[image]

I'm intending to 3D print the model using the stl file. What can I do? I have very very little experience in Blender too. Help please.....Thanks in advance..

Comment: What about it looks unusual? It looks about the same to me (the only difference I see is the lack of smooth shading, but that wouldn't affect a 3D print).

Comment: The surface of the 2nd model looks very rough and spiky. I'm afraid it would affect the final printed product, will it?

Comment: That's due to [*Smooth Shading*](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2773/599). The geometry is no different between the two, but the first example is drawn with smoothed normals on some parts of the mesh. If you want the 3D printed version to have smoother geometry, you'll have to edit it yourself.

Comment: Erm, is it possible to edit the file myself which is downloaded from other sources? I have also this problem where the text under scene has weird boxes ( probably japanese words ). What can I do to fix it? Does that mean that my 3D printed model will have rough and spiky edges too if I didnt edit it ?      http://prntscr.com/8gqa2z

Comment: Well, if it's in blender, you can edit it regardless of where it came from. To fix the fonts, you could try enabling *International fonts* in the preferences (see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3522/599)

Comment: Ahh Thank you very much! Your help is very much appreciated! :)