# Why is this reflection incorect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

I am making an illustration in Cycles Render of a table with a lamp and a Magic-8 ball below it.

Here's what it looks like when I render:

[image]

On closer look, the reflection in the ball is wrong given the curvy object it is reflecting:

[image]

*(image above is the result of 1000 preview samples).*

**Here are a couple more view of the scene and its data:**

[image]

*The black ball's material*

[image]

*The lamp's material*

[image]

*Another light source is present.*

[image]

*What the lamp really looks like (y'know, IKEA).*

I have tried full global illumination in the render settings, various sub surf modifiers to the lamp and to the ball, Multiple Importance on and off, but this didn't change a thing.

Comment: I think it's not the fault of IKEA lamp (though I'm not a big fan of their designs BTW ;)).It's rather the fact your sphere is not smoothed (Tool Shelf-->Tools-->Shading-Smooth). Oh, and you may give your sphere a Subsurf modifier first.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2773/599

Comment: @Gonzou is right, you should turn on smooth shading on your sphere.  Smooth shading smooths the [normals](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21190/what-are-face-normals) across flat faces creating the illusion of curvature.  It also wouldn't hurt to add a subsurf modifier too.

Comment: @Gonzou thanks, friend! Looks like an answer rather than a comment, feel free to magically transform it to an answer

Comment: Oh, yeah, it's a duplicate, you're right! I looked for it for a while though... Should I delete it?

Comment: Can you make the comment an answer to be accepted and upvoted/close this question? thanks