# reflections look pixelated in render-result:

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I created a scene with a big reflective object in the front. unfortunately the refelctions seem to have much bigger pixels than the rest of the scene. As a work-around I thought about rendering the reflective area again in a higher resolution but I assume there is a better way of solving this. I am looking for a time-saving solution.

Which render-values do I have to change in order to get rid of this problem without increasing render-time too much?

I am using blender 2.78[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Problem solved:[image]

Comment: What about the object's shading model? Is it set to smooth? Could you show a solid view of the scene and the material setup?

Comment: I can't see it clearly the shading of the lamp, but I see that many of your rounded objects with flat shading (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading). Also the scene has lots of polygons without seeming very complex. I think you are subdividing the objects to make them smooth by geometry instead of relying on faces. See for example https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/how-can-i-make-a-circular-object-appear-perfectly-round/2778#2778 and tell if this could be the case.

Comment: The high number of polygons comes from the small items on the shelves (bottles, cans, glasses). They have a lot of detail.
The lamp has been smoothed with subsurf-modifier

Comment: So the shading of the lamp object is set to Smooth? Can you confirm?

Comment: @Carlo: no, it's set to flat because I wanted a very sharp edge at the bottom. I will try rendering it smooth.

Comment: There's a modifier to control wich edges should be sharp in a smooth object, but the overall shading should be smooth. It's the **Edge Split** modifier, in combination with marking sharp edges in edit mode.

Comment: You are perfectly right, changing the setting to smooth and adding the edge split modifier solved the problem without changing the appearance of the object. thank you!

Comment: @Michaela please don't write "solved" as part of the question.  instead, write an answer to your own question detailing what you did. Otherwise the question remains "unanswered" in the system. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36274/reflection-is-quad-dependent-and-looks-non-realistic/36280#36280