# How can I make my selected edges render at a smooth angle?

Tags: normals, edges

In comparison, Autodesk Maya had a normals modifier tool in the toolbar which you could select Soften Edge or Harden Edge. Soften Edge would make edges render up to 180 degrees giving it a smooth look without adding any meshes/geometry. I've tried searching many tutorials about Blender how to simply mark any selected edge to appear smooth, but it goes into some crazy process involving smooth all then edge modifiers/bevel steps which actually adds geometry overall.

This video shows what I'm trying to do in Blender, does Blender have anything as easy to mark edges smooth/hard?: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOoZ-wvGmrQ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a circular object appear perfectly round?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/how-can-i-make-a-circular-object-appear-perfectly-round)

Comment: Have you tried AutoSmooth? on the Object Data tab, set the angle Smooth kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

Go into edit mode, select all edges, press shift+E and drag away from mesh to harden edges. Repeat the process while dragging towards the mesh to re soften soften the selected edges.